# Is it possible to have a button which can be moved

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

A friend of mind started a flutter project. He asked me if it is possible to set a button like the floating button of whatsapp and which will be movable by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to code a container as a button and add a `custom animation` if that is the question you're asking.

If not What you are looking for is a `Draggable widget`. You can then handle the translation using onDraggableCanceled which is passed and offset that you can be used to update the placement - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget

And there is a couple of `animation` we can do for a `button` in a flutter.

Refer to this - https://medium.com/flutter-community/animated-send-button-in-flutter-94c1834268b1

Comment: I will check the links and tell you if the question is answered

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, for the sake of simplicity I would prefer you to check out Stack Widget, where you can give coordinates to each Widget(button in your case) and move them.

check out this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/1qlgbNN0BaE

Comment: please add example code. sometime link may be moved or deleted